# How to avoid: ndk-build adds lib prefix to shared libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

On using `$BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` as shown below, and calling `ndk-build`, I get a library named `libmyaudio.so`

```
LOCAL_MODULE := myaudio
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := loop.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-unused-parameter $(INCLUDE_PATH)
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What can I change in `Android.mk` to ensure that built file is **`myaudio.so`** instead of `libmyaudio.so`

Comment: Why? Libraries prefixed by lib are a convention that every tool is going to expect.

Comment: @Dan except dlopen(). Android HALs don't use names starting with lib: e.g. bluetooth.default.so, audio.primary.default.so etc. and they are loaded through a dlopen().
I asked this question because I was suspecting a CTS issue due to this. Turns out it wasn't related to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME`:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := myaudio
```

From the NDK documentation:

> This optional variable allows you to override the names that the build system uses by default for files that it generates. [...] Note: You cannot override filepath or file extension.